# best intuitive books/video lectures to read topology and functional analysis

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request, online-resources, book-recommendation

What are the best intuitive books/video lectures to read topology and functional analysis ? I am aware of basic linear algebra, analysis and measure theory.

Comment: coursera had a great functional analysis class taught by a French Professor (Lectures were in English). Unfortunately they have take it down since the course is complete. :(

Comment: Off the top of my head, try Munkres for topology and Lax for functional analysis. Stein and Shakarchi have a functional book, though it includes other topics.

Comment: Since videos are mentioned in the post, I have added ([tag:online-resources]) tag. If you think it is not suitable here; feel free to remove this tag.

Comment: I imagine the class Jack Dawkins is talking about is [this one.](https://www.coursera.org/course/functionalanalysis) It's being offered again in September

Comment: Or one of the Ecole Normale Supérieure (ENS)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here is my short list of **Visual / intuitive books about Topology :**

- *Intuitive Concepts in Elementary Topology*. - Arnold
- *From Geometry To Topology* - H. Graham Flegg
- *Classical Topology and Combinatorial Group Theory* - John Stillwell
- *Three-Dimensional Geometry and Topology*  - Bill Thurston & Silvio Levy
- *The shape of space*. - Jeff Weeks or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3BlLo1QfmU

**Other resources** :

- this website for games about Topology : http://geometrygames.org

[EDIT] Most of these books are listed in the question about visual math books : 
[are-there-other-nice-math-books-close-to-the-style-of-tristan-needham](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31879/are-there-other-nice-math-books-close-to-the-style-of-tristan-needham)

Comment: I would add Mike Starbird's topology video series. http://www.thegreatcourses.com/tgc/professors/professor_detail.aspx?pid=191